# change event not firing for dynamic content in jquery modal dialog & chrome browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, google-chrome

I've written an autocomplete JSF custom component which renders an `<input>` and when
text is typed in it sends an ajax request to the server. The results are displayed
as a `<select>` with `<option>` tags.

If I have `<custom:autocomplete id="findTeam"/>` the component will render a structure
like this:

```
<span id="findTeam>
  <input id="findTeam_input"/>
  <select id="findTeam_listbox">
    <option ...>
  </select>
</span>
```

I use jQuery to bind the change event for the `<select>` so that I know when an entry has
been selected from the list. This generally works ok, but the change event is not
firing when I'm using the component inside a jquery ui 1.8.16 modal dialog box when using
a chrome browser (v15.0.874.106 m). It works ok if the dialog is not modal, and in IE8
it works ok with a modal dialog box. So when the `<select>` is rendered and I click on
one of the options, nothing happens - it remains displayed but I can't select anything.

I don't see any errors in the js console and I'm not really sure what to try next. Here
is a sample of the ajax response from the server:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
    <changes>
        <update id="findTeam">
            <![CDATA[
            <script>
                jQuery(function($){
                    com.corejsf.ajaxSetup("mojarra.ab('findTeam',event,'change',0,'addButton')");
                    $('#findTeam').hover(com.corejsf.compFocusSet,com.corejsf.compFocusClear);
                });
            </script>
            <span id="findTeam">
                <input id="findTeam_input" type="text" name="findTeam_input" autocomplete="off" value="tea" />
                <script>
                    jQuery(function($){
                        $('#findTeam_input').bind('keydown','#findTeam_listbox',com.corejsf.inputKeydown);
                        $('#findTeam_input').bind('blur','#findTeam',com.corejsf.compBlur);
                        $('#findTeam_input').bind('keyup',{id:'#findTeam',minChars:3},com.corejsf.inputKeyup);
                        $('#findTeam_input').bind('mousedown','#findTeam',com.corejsf.inputClick);var cid='#findTeam_input';
                        $(cid).focus().focus().click();$(cid).val($(cid).val());
                    });
                </script>
                <select id="findTeam_listbox" name="findTeam_listbox" size="10" style="position: absolute">
                    <option value="cfdb36cd-ebfa-49b9-941e-2a74d7b82aef">Team 5</option>
                    <option value="a206fbbc-552d-4b7b-b2d3-dc1a50f98667">Team 6</option>
                    <option value="bc5f9f1d-ef76-452f-9101-bff703efbf38">Team 7</option>
                    <option value="2a43ff65-d170-45a7-9bf0-ec237d51603d">Team 8</option>
                    <option value="7112ca7d-75ea-4957-a830-7ef7b54e18f5">Team 9</option>
                </select>
                <script>
                jQuery(function($){
                    $('#findTeam_listbox').position({my:'left top',at:'left bottom',of:$('#findTeam_input'),collision:'fit'});
                    $('#findTeam_listbox').dropShadow({left:4,top:4,blur:1});
                    $('#findTeam_listbox').bind('change',com.corejsf.listClick);
                    $('#findTeam_listbox').bind('blur','#findTeam',com.corejsf.compBlur);
                });
                </script>
            </span>
            ]]>
        </update>
        <update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
            <![CDATA[8331589387080754551:-7156357472895110486]]>
        </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

I've tried using .live() instead of .bind() but this doesn't help, could this be some
sort of security restriction in chrome? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a security restriction. You must rebind after the generation of the modal box!

Comment: I've tried re-binding in a dialogopen event handler, but still nothing happens. I've put alerts in both the dialogopen handler (which is being called) and the listClick() handler (which isn't). Any ideas? When I think about it, the findTeam_listbox doesn't exist when the dialog is opened, only when some text is typed into the input and some results are returned from the server. The change event is bound after the select tag is rendered. Thanks for your response.